# Owasp-Zap Securiy Testing Using azure pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

This is the reference doc I have followed to set up the Azure pipeline
https://medium.com/adessoturkey/owasp-zap-security-tests-in-azure-devops-fe891f5402a4

below i am sharing screenshort of the pipeline failed:

[image]

Could you please help here to resolve the issue I have exactly followed the medium article to implement the task....

Those who aware on this could you please share your taughts.

This is the pipeline script i am using.

trigger: none

stages:

- stage: 'buildstage'
  jobs:

  - job: buildjob
    pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

    ## - checkout: self

    ## - checkout: owasap-zap

    - bash: "docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx:1.14.2"
      displayName: "App Container"
    - bash: |
      chmod -R 777  ./
      docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-full-scan.py -t http://$(ip -f inet -o addr show docker0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 1):80 -x xml_report.xml
      true
      displayName: "Owasp Container Scan"

    ## - displayName: "PowerShell Script"

    - powershell: |
      $XslPath = "owasp-zap/xml_to_nunit.xslt"
      $XmlInputPath = "xml_report.xml"
      $XmlOutputPath = "converted_report.xml"
      $XslTransform = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
      $XslTransform.Load($XslPath)
      $XslTransform.Transform($XmlInputPath, $XmlOutputPath)
      displayName: "PowerShell Script"
    - task: PublishTestResults@2
      displayName: "Publish Test Results"
      inputs:
      testResultsFiles: converted_report.xml
      testResultsFormat: NUnit
      # task: PublishTestResults@2

    ## stage: buildstage

Comment: Can you share the pipeline code? But in short - the PowerShell script looks for a file which isn't there. So maybe it has a spelling error, or it is at a different location, or it was never generated. The output of the previous task would be helpful as well

Comment: i have added the script in the  above section please find

Answer (score 0):

According to the YAML file, you want to checkout multiple repositories in your pipeline, but it seems you haven't define a repository resource like mentioned in the document you shared.

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: <repo_name>
      type: git
      name: <project_name>/<repo_name>
      ref: refs/heads/master
```

And according to the screenshot you shared, you only checkout out one repo. Which cause the location of file xml_to_nunit.xslt is different from owasp-zap/xml_to_nunit.xslt. If you only checkout one repo, the location of xml_to_nunit.xslt should be current directory, thus, just define `$XslPath` in the PowerShell script as `"xml_to_nunit.xslt"`.

**Edit**

If the repository that contain `"xml_to_nunit.xslt"` file is in the same organization as the repository run for your pipeline, you need to checkout the repository by using [Inline syntax checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#inline-syntax-checkout) like below or define repository resource.

```
- checkout: git://MyProject/MyRepo # Azure Repos Git repository in the same organization
```

You could also add one more command `ls` before the PowerShell script to list the files in current directory. Aim to figure out where is "xml_to_nunit.xslt".

[image]

Comment: yes but in the repository there is only one file so i have mentioned the name of repo only

Comment: Hi @regardingtheZapsecurity, only mention the name of repo won't checkout the repo. I have edited my answer, please check it.